# Evict cache from different JVM

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I am using EHCache in my Spring/Hibernate application. But database is shared between main application and another smaller ones (each is running in separate JVM). All parties can change DB data.

The problem here is that after changes done by 3rd parties, cache of main app becomes invalid since it doesn't know anything about those changes.

The first idea I have is no notify main app (for example by JMS) that entity with particular ID was changed and inside main app I can evict it from cache explicitly. This could solve the problem but probably there are some other best-practices can be applied here?

Comment: The best practice here is to recognize that any time you have independent processes accessing shared mutable state, you have no guarantees that any given process will see the most recent version of that state. So design accordingly, and if you absolutely must see the latest state, bypass the cache and use transactions.

Comment: But it is not suitable for me. Main app works with data all the time and side-apps can update data once an hour. I do not want to bypass caches in main app.

Comment: Reread what I wrote. You're dealing with a fundamental problem of distributed systems. Either you _need_ latest state, in which case you _can't_ use a cache, or not, in which case you design your system to work with stale data. Adding communication between apps can certainly reduce the window of stale data, but it can't eliminate it.

Comment: Agree, here I have two possibilities. In particular case I need to choose cache. What approach of notification is mostly suitable here?

Comment: Notify the main app when the others have finished their work, and use that notification to purge the entire cache. Don't try to evict individual objects. Use whatever technology you're familiar with.